# Add values to dictionary / tuple

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a tuple which I convert to a dict. The outcome is e.g.:

```
{'test-rz-01.test.de': '10.60.1.100','test2.test.de': '10.60.1.10’}
```

I now need to add "static" content to each entry so that it looks like a list of dicts:

```
[{'name': 'test-rz-01.test.de', 'ipv4addr':'10.60.1.100', 'view': 
'External', 'zone': 'test.de'}, {'name': 'test2.test.de', 'ipv4addr': 
'10.60.1.10’, 'view': 'External', 'zone': 'test.de'}]
```

what would be the "best" way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please post your code and tell us where you got stuck. You should also visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your dictionary

```
>>> d = {'test-rz-01.htwk-leipzigtest.de': '10.60.1.100', 'test2.test.de': '10.60.1.10'}
```

employ a list comprehension in which you construct the dicts.

```
>>> [{'name':domain, 'ipv4addr':ip, 'view': 'External', 'zone': 'test.de'}
...  for domain, ip in d.items()]
```

output:

```
[{'ipv4addr': '10.60.1.10', 'name': 'test2.test.de', 'zone': 'test.de', 'view': 'External'}, {'ipv4addr': '10.60.1.100', 'name': 'test-rz-01.htwk-leipzigtest.de', 'zone': 'test.de', 'view': 'External'}]
```

Comment: I changed my original question to reflect that I need a list of dicts. My mistake, was a typo. I'm struggling a bit to convert your suggestion into code